# Android error "android.app.Application does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector"

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm trying to run my app and every time I click on a button and it calls a specific Activity (ExtendedActivity) I get the following error :

```
Process: com.converter.android.dailycope, PID: 28573
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.converter.android.dailycope/com.converter.android.dailycope.ui.extended.ExtendedActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.app.Application does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.app.Application does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector
                      at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject(AndroidInjection.java:48)
                      at com.converter.android.dailycope.ui.base.BaseActivity.performDependencyInjection(BaseActivity.java:105)
                      at com.converter.android.dailycope.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:35)
                      at com.converter.android.dailycope.ui.extended.ExtendedActivity.onCreate(ExtendedActivity.java:34)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
```

The error is on line `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`

```java
    public class ExtendedActivity extends BaseActivity<ActivityExtendedBinding, ExtendedViewModel> {

    @Inject
    ViewModelProvider.Factory mViewModelFactory;
    ActivityExtendedBinding mActivityStartBinding;
    private ExtendedViewModel mExtendedViewModel;

    private String caps, horos, tipo;
    private String data, prefString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    (...)
```

The class where I have the HasActivityInjector

```java
    public class Cope extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        DaggerExtendedComponent.builder().application(this).build().inject(this);

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
        }

    }


    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I solved my problem adding `android:name` in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: You answer is correct but with lake of description.

Comment: thnx for your answer. these little things sometimes makes me go crazy and wastes a lot of time

Answer (score 31):

If your implementation is correct then please check in manifest file if you have add/assigned the name of Application Tag.

```
 <application
    android:name=".base.BaseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your application class should implement `HasActivityInjector`. Use official [documentation](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) to setup dagger properly.

Comment: My application has a HasActivityInjector (I've edited the question). The problem is not that.

Comment: @porthfind, do you extend your `BaseActivity` from `DaggerActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue exactly. Just clean and rebuild the project solved the issue.